# How to Generate Counts of Elements Returned from Map Function?

Tags: couchdb

I have a map function

```
function (doc) {
    for(var n =0; n<doc.Observations.length; n++){
        emit(doc.Scenario, doc.Observations[n].Label);
    } 
}
```

the above returns the following:

```
{"key":"Splunk","value":"Organized"},
{"key":"Splunk","value":"Organized"},
{"key":"Splunk","value":"Organized"},
{"key":"Splunk","value":"Generate"},
{"key":"Splunk","value":"Ingest"}
```

I"m looking to design a reduce function that will then return the counts of the above values, something akin to:

```
Organized: 3
Generate: 1
Ingest: 1
```

My map function has to filter on my Scenario field, hence why I have it as an emitted key in the map function.

I've tried using a number of the built in reduce functions, but I end up getting count of rows, or nothing at all as the functions available don't apply.

I just need to access the counts of each of the elements that appear in the values field.  Also, the values present here are representative, there could 100s of different types of values found in the values field for what that's worth.

I really appreciate the help!

Here's sample input:

```
{
    "_id": "dummyId",
    "test": "test",
    "Team": "Alpha",
    "CreatedOnUtc": "2019-06-20T21:39:09.5940830Z",
    "CreatedOnLocal": "2019-06-20T17:39:09.5940830-04:00",
    "Participants": [
        {
            "Name": "A",
            "Role": "Person"
        }
    ],
    "Observations": [
        {
           "Label": "Report",
        },
        {
            "Label": "Ingest",
        },
        {
            "Label": "Generate",
        },
        {
            "Label": "Ingest",
        }
     ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the map by "value" as your key and associate an increment to that key to make sure a count is maintained. And then you can print your map which should look as you are requesting for.

Comment: Close. So I could, but I only want to count entities by a key that I'm passing into the view.  So my map function has the key doc.Scenario because I'm passing in a "Scenario" id that the filters for me, giving me back only values associated with that key.   So yes, I could do an emit(doc.Observations[n].Label, 1) then reduce, but that will give me counts of Labels across all documents.  I only want counts of Labels where the Scenario equals what I pass in.